# Shoping cart addition of item quantity with the help of jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have web page where different product can be added to the cart by the user and i am using a calculator for adding the quantity i am somehow successful to add the quantity of last selected item till 9 using the calculator buttons which i have upto 9 what about if user want the 10 quantity please help me out because i am stuck .
[here is fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zazikhan1/bvWQr/)

here is html.

```
<body>
<div class="container">

   <div class="left">

     <div class="left-top">
        <ul class="add">

        </ul>
        <ul style="float:right">
              <li id="total" data-value="0"></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="left-bottom">
        <div class="box-left">
          <div class="btnBG">
             <span>Cash Journal-Test</span>
          </div>
          <div class="btnBG">
             <span>Bank Journal-Test</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box-right">
           <div class="box-right-left" id="box-right-left">
                   <div class="btnSM">
                      <span><button data-value="1">1</button></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="btnSM">
                     <span><button data-value="2">2</button></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="btnSM">
                     <span><button data-value="3">3</button></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="btnSM">
                     <span><button data-value="4">4</button></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="btnSM">
                     <span><button data-value="5">5</button></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="btnSM">
                     <span><button data-value="6">6</button></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="btnSM">
                     <span><button data-value="7">7</button></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="btnSM">
                     <span><button data-value="8">8</button></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="btnSM">
                     <span><button data-value="9">9</button></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="btnSM">
                     <span>+/-</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="btnSM">
                     <span>0</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="btnSM">
                     <span>.</span>
                  </div>
           </div>
           <div class="box-right-right">
                 <div class="btnSM">
                     <span>Qty</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="btnSM">
                     <span>Disc</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="btnSM">
                     <span>Price</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="btnSM">
                     <span>*</span>
                  </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="right">
       <div class="right-top1">
          <a href="#"><img src="images/home_w.png" /></a>
          <span class="search"><span class="img"></span><input type="search" name="search" placeholder="Search Products" /></span>
       </div>
      <div class="right-top">
        <div class="box1">
           <img src="images/col.png" />
           <h1>Beverges</h1>
         </div>
         <div class="box1">
           <img src="images/free.png" />
           <h1>Food</h1>
         </div>
         <div class="box1">
           <img src="images/fru.png" />
           <h1>Fresh Fruits</h1>
         </div>
         <div class="box1">
           <img src="images/veg.png" />
           <h1>Fresh Vegetables</h1>
         </div>
         <div class="box1">
           <img src="images/camera.png" />
           <h1>Others</h1>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="right-bottom">
         <div class="box2">
             <p data-value="800">pkr 800.0</p>
           <img src="images/col.png" />
           <h1>Beverges</h1>
         </div>
         <div class="box2">
          <p data-value="700">pkr 700.0</p>
           <img src="images/col.png" />
           <h1>Beverges</h1>
         </div>
         <div class="box2">
          <p data-value="700">pkr 700.0</p>
           <img src="images/col.png" />
           <h1>Beverges</h1>
         </div>
         <div class="box2">
          <p data-value="700">pkr 700.0</p>
           <img src="images/col.png" />
           <h1>Beverges</h1>
         </div>
         <div class="box2">
          <p data-value="700">pkr 700.0</p>
           <img src="images/col.png" />
           <h1>Beverges</h1>
         </div>
         <div class="box2">
          <p data-value="700">pkr 700.0</p>
           <img src="images/col.png" />
           <h1>Beverges</h1>
         </div>
         <div class="box2">
          <p data-value="700">pkr 700.0</p>
           <img src="images/col.png" />
           <h1>Beverges</h1>
         </div>
         <div class="box2">
          <p data-value="700">pkr 700.0</p>
           <img src="images/col.png" />
           <h1>Beverges</h1>
         </div>
         <div class="box2">
          <p data-value="700">pkr 700.0</p>
           <img src="images/col.png" />
           <h1>Beverges</h1>
         </div>
         <div class="box2">
          <p data-value="700">pkr 700.0</p>
           <img src="images/col.png" />
           <h1>Beverges</h1>
         </div>
         <div class="box2">
          <p data-value="700">pkr 700.0</p>
           <img src="images/col.png" />
           <h1>Beverges</h1>
         </div>
         <div class="box2">
          <p data-value="700">pkr 700.0</p>
           <img src="images/col.png" />
           <h1>Beverges</h1>
         </div>
         <div class="box2">
          <p data-value="800">pkr 700.0</p>
           <img src="images/col.png" />
           <h1>Beverges</h1>
         </div>
         <div class="box2">
          <p data-value="700">pkr 700.0</p>
           <img src="images/col.png" />
           <h1>Beverges</h1>
         </div>
         <div class="box2">
          <p data-value="800">pkr 800.0</p>
           <img src="images/col.png" />
           <h1>Beverg</h1>
         </div>
      </div>

   </div>
</div>
```

here is javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.box2').click(function(){
      var price=$(this).find('p').html();
      var product=$(this).find('h1').html();
      price = price.replace("pkr ","") * 1;
      var price1=parseInt(price)+ parseInt($("#total").attr('data-value'));
      $("#total").attr('data-value', price1);
      $("#total").html('$'+price1);
       if(product)
       {
           if($(".add li:first").html()== undefined)
                { 
                //$('<li><input type="checkbox" name="selectedItem" /></li>').prependTo('.add');
                 $('<li>', {html: price}).prependTo('.add');
                 $('<li>', {html: product}).prependTo('.add');
                }
           else
                {
                 $('<li>', {html: product}).appendTo('.add');
                 $('<li>', {html: price}).appendTo('.add'); 
                }
       }
  });
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#box-right-left").find(".btnSM").on('click', function(e)
    {   
        e.preventDefault();
        var price1=$(".add").find('li:last').html();
        price1 = price1.replace("pkr ","") * 1;
        alert(price1);
        var price=parseInt(price1)* parseInt($(this).find('button').attr('data-value'));
        $(".add li:last").html(price);
        var total=parseInt($("#total").attr('data-value'))+ parseInt(price)-parseInt(price1);
        $("#total").attr('data-value', total);
        $("#total").html('$'+total);
        //alert(total);
     });
});
</script>
```

Comment: what is problem for 10 and more items?

Comment: the problem is how can i select 10 it need two clicks but i have nested each button with click how i am gona add 10 quantity

Comment: check out my fiddle than you will better understand my problem i hope

Comment: Your fiddle adds 10 and more elements properly ,what is problem?

Comment: no down check the calculator the elements are adding perfectly but what if i want to add quantity i have gave the calculator to add the quantity to last selected item

Comment: after adding the element try out the calculator

Comment: you properly tell working of your calculator.Dont get anything from your fiddle ,  your question explanation,Explain properly. Why you have 1,2 3 etc numbers ?what is working?????

Comment: ok let me tell you if user add an item to cart and this user want the same element in 14 quantity what he is going to do is just add the quantity from the calculator but the problem here is i have only 9 button so user can go upto 9 quantity but how can i add 14 quantity to the same element using this calculator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to show button of 10 after 9 because if you wait for the user to click on a 0 after 1 the it will be slow down process and User will not able to process the order now

**User will get annoyed oh!!!!** how can i proceed now so this will be a not good approach if your requirement is more then 9,10 etc

### One solution i can recommend for you is

Or another approach to solve this is to just add drop down after 9 so user can click the drop down

on more approach to this is why you are giving him add **+ your qty -** or give text box to user when he can add the qty

Updated >>>>>>>>>>

**Give one textbox** here  and **one button here** if 
1   2   3
4   5   6
7   8   9
    0

If user click **one 1** the one will be there in textbox if user **press 0** then it will be **10** there so when user click on button at right **10 will be added to cart**

Comment: Ya man there is not a particular one way so you just need is `change your approach`

Comment: but the user need is this one i could done this by using checkbox and textbox and the approach was easy but user is asking for calculator so thats why i am insisting to done this by calculator

Comment: yes thanks you i am doing this by hidden input type and than creating another event of total so in this way user will first select the values and when he will press total the quantity will be multiplied with the item price and will be added to cart thanks alot